# StatusCodePagesMiddleware doesn't intercept exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

For example, in the Index page:

```
public ActionResult OnGet()
{
    //return StatusCode(500);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

My Startup configuration:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

When the `Index.OnGet()` gets executed and throws the exception, the default 500 page of the browser is shown instead of the middleware page but works as expected when explicitly return `StatusCode(500)`.

What I'm looking for is a generic way of handling errors: so I can use for example:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
```

and in the error page, I can customize the HTML depending on the `statusCode` whether it's 4xx or 5xx.